# What topology on $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$ is this?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a Hilbert space and denote the bounded operators on $\mathcal{H}$ by $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$. Further write $P$ for the set of all positive functionals on $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$. Let $\mathcal{T}$ be the smallest topology on $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$ for which the map $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H}) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}, x \mapsto \phi(x)$ is continuous for all $\phi \in P$.

**Question:** Since the topology I defined appears to be very natural, I assume that it has a name or that it coincides with another well-known topology like e.g. the strong operator topology. Can you give me a reference or a proof?

Answer (score 1):

This is the $\sigma(B(\mathcal{H}),B(\mathcal{H})^*)$ topology aka the *weak topology*. It is not the same as the weak operator topology.